# How can I generate a unique foreign key while seeding, using Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I've got these two tables linked with a one to one relation. How should the seeders be if I want unique foreign keys in sponsored apartments table?

**Model table Apartments:**

```
public function sponsoredapartment() {

    return $this -> hasOne(SponsoredApartment::class);
}
```

**Model table Sponsored Apartments**

```
public function apartment() {

    return $this -> belongsTo(Apartment::class);
}
```

**Migrations Apartments**

```
Schema::create('apartments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table -> string('title')->required();
        $table -> string('rooms')->required();
        $table -> integer('bed');
        $table -> integer('bathroom');
        $table -> integer('area');
        $table -> string('address');
        $table -> string('url_img');
        $table -> string('features');

        $table -> bigInteger('landlord_id')->index()->unsigned();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Migrations Sponsored Apartments**

```
    Schema::create('sponsored_apartments', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table -> id();

        $table -> date('expired_date');
        $table -> bigInteger('apartment_id') -> unsigned() -> index();
        $table -> bigInteger('sponsor_id') -> unsigned() -> index();

        $table -> timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: With `seeders` you specify the data to be inserted, so you'd be responsible for ensuring values are unique.

Comment: Hey author, please do not do `$variable -> method`, do `$variable->method`. It is related to codestyle and other possible problems when editing... Read more about it (PSR).

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you for the advice. What does PSR stay for?

Comment: @Geeogee PSR stands for PHP Standard Recommendations, [here is the official site](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/). But you can read more in other places if you google `PSR` and add any word that would suggest understanding it or learning more about it like `PSR good recommendations` and stuff.